# Distribute objects horizontally on canvas with fabricJS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have 7 objects (SVG) that has to be distributed horizontally on the canvas but I can't figure out how to do it.

The code below kindly works except that in the for loop it doesn't wait for the image is loaded so the result are images aligned but in random order. More the value of scale inside the fabric method `loadSVGFromURL` is always `2`.

I tried also to put `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` in a separate function but then I can't use this method counting objects width.

like:

```
function loadSVG(url, scale) {

}
```

Is there any easier method to achieve my goal?

Below my code:

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.$refs.image, {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
})

this.canvas.clear()


var width = this.canvas.getWidth(),
    imgsArr = [
        {url: "/storage/slot-images/image_162.svg", scale: 2},
        {url: "/images/storymachine/arrow.svg", scale: 0.5},
        {url: "/storage/slot-images/image_31.svg", scale: 2},
        {url: "/images/storymachine/arrow.svg", scale: 0.5},
        {url: "/storage/slot-images/image_149.svg", scale: 2},
        {url: "/images/storymachine/arrow.svg", scale: 0.5},
        {url: "/storage/slot-images/image_193.svg", scale: 2},
    ],
    cacheWidth = 0


for (var i = 0; i < imgsArr.length; i++) {
    var url = imgsArr[i].url,
        scale = imgsArr[i].scale

        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, (objs, opts) => {
            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objs, opts)
            this.canvas.add(obj)
            obj.center()
            obj.set({
                selectable: false,
                centeredScaling: true,
                scaleX: scale,
                scaleY: scale,
                left: cacheWidth,
            })
            cacheWidth = cacheWidth + obj.getScaledWidth()
        })
        this.canvas.renderAll()
}
```

the link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonepozzobon/Lpjz2x38)

Comment: The width of the fabric image will be different from object to object?

Comment: @MariusTurcu yes, it's different and it is scaled differently. I'm using `obj.getScaledWidth()` to get their width.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on jsfiddle? I think I have an ideea for this

Comment: `loadSVGFromURL` is async, you can use `let scale = imgsArr[i].scale;`

Comment: @MariusTurcu https://jsfiddle.net/simonepozzobon/Lpjz2x38/

Comment: @Durga not working, now is always 0.5

Comment: @AngusSimons [check](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjz2x38/10/), if you want as synchronous,then you can use [recursion](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjz2x38/16/)

Comment: @Durga amazing now they are loaded in order...but not distributed on the full width

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an example for showing how you can distribute objects horizontally with equal spacing in fabric js**

```
function distributeHorizontal(canvas,event) {
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
var totalWidth = activeObject.width;
var totalBoxesWidth = _.reduce(
  activeObject._objects,
  function (sum, object) {
    return sum + object.width;
  },
  0
);
var objects = _.sortBy(activeObject._objects, function (object) {
  return object.left;
});
let spacing = (totalWidth - totalBoxesWidth) / (objects.length - 1);
var previousObject = objects.shift();
objects.pop();
_.each(objects, function (object, i) {
  object.set({
    left: previousObject.left + previousObject.width * previousObject.scaleX + spacing
  })
  object.setCoords();
  previousObject = object;
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this distribution logic using the below code

```
function sortByLeft(objects) {
    objects.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.left - b.left
    });
    return objects;
}

function sortByTop(objects) {
    objects.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.top - b.top
    });
    return objects;
}

function distributesX() {

    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

    var totalWidth = activeObject.width;
    var totalBoxesWidth = 0;
    activeObject.forEachObject(function(item) {
        totalBoxesWidth += item.getScaledWidth();
    })

    var objects = sortByLeft(activeObject._objects);

    canvas.renderAll();

    let spacing = (totalWidth - totalBoxesWidth) / (objects.length - 1);
    var previousObject = objects.shift();
    objects.pop();

    objects.forEach(function(object) {
        object.set({
            left: previousObject.left + previousObject.width * previousObject.scaleX + spacing
        })
        object.setCoords();
        previousObject = object;
    })

    canvas.renderAll();
}

function distributesY() {

    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

    var totalHeight = activeObject.height;
    var totalBoxesHeight = 0;
    activeObject.forEachObject(function(item) {
        totalBoxesHeight += item.getScaledHeight();
    })

    var objects = sortByTop(activeObject._objects);

    canvas.renderAll();

    let spacing = (totalHeight - totalBoxesHeight) / (objects.length - 1);
    var previousObject = objects.shift();
    objects.pop();

    objects.forEach(function(object) {
        object.set({
            top: previousObject.top + previousObject.height * previousObject.scaleY + spacing
        })
        object.setCoords();
        previousObject = object;
    })

    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: If you need to work with rotated objects, too, you can use fabric.js' "getBoundingRect()" to calculate the width of a rotated object. Thanks for the code, it helped me with my distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result
https://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/Lpjz2x38/31/

```js
el = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas(el, {
    backgroundColor: '#E8E0C8'
  }),
  imgsArr = [{
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/slot-machine/public/images/storymachine/300icone_162.svg",
      scale: 2
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/animazione-menu/public/images/storymachine/arrow.svg",
      scale: 0.5
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/slot-machine/public/images/storymachine/300icone_31.svg",
      scale: 2
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/animazione-menu/public/images/storymachine/arrow.svg",
      scale: 0.5
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/slot-machine/public/images/storymachine/300icone_149.svg",
      scale: 2
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/animazione-menu/public/images/storymachine/arrow.svg",
      scale: 0.5
    },
    {
      url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonepozzobon/shortology-new/slot-machine/public/images/storymachine/300icone_193.svg",
      scale: 2
    },
  ]



let cacheWidth = 0
var total = 0;
var interval = setInterval(checkImages, 200);
for (var i = 0; i < imgsArr.length; i++) {
  var url = imgsArr[i].url
  let scale = imgsArr[i].scale

  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, (function(i) {
    return function(objs, opts) {
      var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objs, opts)
      canvas.add(obj).renderAll()
      obj.center()
      obj.set({
        selectable: false,
        centeredScaling: true,
        scaleX: scale,
        scaleY: scale,
        left: cacheWidth,
        id: 'object_' + i,
        visible: false
      })

      cacheWidth = cacheWidth + obj.getScaledWidth();
      total++;
    }

  })(i))
}
canvas.renderAll()

// make the canvas responsive
resize()
window.addEventListener('resize', resize)

// resize the canvas
function resize() {
  var el = document.getElementById('container'),
    size = el.offsetWidth,
    scaleFactor = canvas.getWidth() / 1000

  // resize canvas
  canvas.setWidth(size)
  canvas.setHeight(size)

  // scale using scale Factor and zoom
  canvas.setZoom(scaleFactor)
  canvas.calcOffset()
  canvas.renderAll()
}

function checkImages() {
  var cacheWidth = 0;
  if (total == imgsArr.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgsArr.length; i++) {
      //   debugger
      obj = getObjectById('object_' + i);
      if (obj.length) {
        obj[0].set('left', cacheWidth);
        obj[0].set('visible', true);
        cacheWidth = cacheWidth + obj[0].getScaledWidth();
      }

    }
    canvas.renderAll();
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}

function getObjectById(id) {
  return canvas.getObjects().filter(function(o) {
    return o.id === id;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
       <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Initialy i set `visible` on false. I used `setInterval` to check when are images are loaded on the canvas. When all are loaded I repeat the position process. I map the position using `object.id`

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's better the way shown by @Durga in the comments above, without `setInterval` btw still not distributed on the whole canvas not even aligned :(

Comment: FYI, you can use snippet here